# Google Maps API open multiple info windows by default

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Is it possible to open all info windows by default. I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      maxWidth: 160
});

// Add the markers and infowindows to the map
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: icons[iconCounter]
    });

    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [google-maps-api-2 (the deprecated and turned off version of the api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference)?  Developing new code for that version of the API is not a good idea.  Also, note that the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics) supports multiple InfoWindows, v2 does not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code only includes one infowindow, if you want them *all* to open, you need to create an infowindow for each marker.

**Update:** didn't notice when I wrote this that this question is tagged `google-maps-api-2`.  This answer will only work for the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics), [the deprecated Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference), only supports a single infowindow at a time.

```
// Add the markers and infowindows to the map
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: icons[iconCounter]
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: locations[i][0],
      maxWidth: 160
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
```

Comment: Creating local variable for `infowindow` solve my problem +1