# How to open all the info windows on google map

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I would like to know if there is a way to open all the info windows by default when the map is opened and don't have to click on the marker to show it.

I mean I want to open all the info windows for all markers when the user opens the map

Comment: Can't you simply `open()` each info window when you're creating it? What is the problem.? For an accurate answer, You've to provide more information such as how are you creating the map and respective info windows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming you already got your markers up and running you just need an `for` loop in the initialize function, which will be fired when the map loaded.

So the loop just runs over all markers you stored and opens the infowindow of the certain marker.

```
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                    mapOptions);
    var markers = new Array(); // Where you markers are stored
    //Init Markers, init Infowindows and the other stuff..
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i){
        infowindow.open(map, markers[i]);
    };
}

//When the map loads the initialize function will be called
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: icons[iconCounter]
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: locations[i][0],
  maxWidth: 160
});
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

}

or view 
[Google Maps API open multiple info windows by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514388/google-maps-api-open-multiple-info-windows-by-default)

Comment: What is locations..? what is map..? what is icons..?

Comment: you have google maps code??
please read it carefully

Comment: Those are variable names somebody declared for their use. not something that is there in javascript or google maps. Simply copy pasting another answer here is pointless. google maps codes..? LOL